# How organize filter to set default action in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The problem:

How to organize filter for return default action for controller, as an example i have action in database, actions have order i want to return action in my order not in:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional }
```

it should be exactly filter or something else for not include in controller - witch means if i create controller i should not include any futures for ordering. ordering will be apply automatically.